# In an HTML table, can a numeric value be expressed with comma formatting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

In Visual FoxPro, a number can be formatted in a textbox or grid and still be seen by the program as just a number, even though it is shown with commas and period format.

Presently I'm inserting data into a DataTable Jquery as follows:

```
oTable.fnAddData( ["Bogus data","1,541,512.52","12.5%","0","0","0"]);
```

But I would like to be entering the data as follows and yet show it with the commas for clarity:

```
oTable.fnAddData( ["Bogus data",1541512.52,"12.5%","0","0","0"]);
```

The reason is that when you sort the rows on this column, the character string in the first example will produce a mess.  the numbers, hopefully will produce a well ordered list.

If you have any other suggestions on how to fix the sorting of the character number column please suggest it...

TIA

Dennis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sort plugin for formatted numbers is detailed here, by the author of DataTables:

http://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting

See "formatted numbers":

> This plug-in will provide numeric sorting for numeric columns which have extra formatting, such as thousands seperators, currency symobols or any other non-numeric data.

```
jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "formatted-num-pre": function ( a ) {
        a = (a==="-") ? 0 : a.replace( /[^\d\-\.]/g, "" );
        return parseFloat( a );
    },

    "formatted-num-asc": function ( a, b ) {
        return a - b;
    },

    "formatted-num-desc": function ( a, b ) {
        return b - a;
    }
} );
```

Comment: Thank you for addressing my question in full Marc.  I am in the middle of trying it out and reading the site you replied.  I assume that numbers cannot be formatted then and will go on with this alternative instead.  I do wish that there was a mask and format, but this will do.  So, thank you for your kindness and help.  This looks promising.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick and dirty way to do it;

```
var number = 1541512.52;
var nicelyformattedNumber = number.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
oTable.fnAddData( ["Bogus data", nicelyformattedNumber, "12.5%","0","0","0"]);
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript)

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, but this will produce a character value for the middle column in the table. The funny thing is that these numbers come to me fully formatted in character format.  I would like to use numbers, as I said above.  Nevertheless, thank you for the kindness of helping me.